# matplotlib change line width on existing skimage plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-image

I am using the plotting function that is encapsulated in skimage to draw matches between two sets of keypoints. In particular, I am using this function: [plot_matches](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.feature.html#skimage.feature.plot_matches)

This works fine but the lines that are drawn are quite thick. I know with matplotlib one can control the line thickness with the `linewidth` parameter in the plot. In this case, the plot function is called by the `plot_matches` function in the link.

The way, I am using it as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage.feature import plot_matches

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.gray()
plot_matches(ax, img1, img2, k1[:, [0, 1]],
             k2[:, [0, 1]], matches, only_matches=True)
ax.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

Is there a way to control the linewidth property in this kind of usage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the `plot_matches` just [hardcodes](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/master/skimage/feature/util.py#L121) the plot parameters according to its internal settings and no further keyword arguments are passed onto the matplotlib function.

An option you have is to use th [rcParams](https://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html) to change the standard linewidth before calling that function.

```
plt.rcParams["lines.linewidth"] = 3
plot_matches(...)
```

Possibly you need to set it back to the default (1.5) after the plot to be able to use the standard in further plots to be produced.

Comment: This works and will suffice for my needs! Many thanks!

Comment: You can also access the last set of lines that were plotted and modify them.

Comment: @MadPhysicist You mean the solution proposed in the other answer? That would change *all* lines. Otherwise, yes, you could loop over the lines in question, like `for i,line in zip(range(matches.shape[0]), ax.lines[::-1]): line.set_linewidth(3)`. Sounds more complicated though.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest. Sure. I had something more complex in mind, but was on mobile at the time so couldn't write it up or see the other answer in time.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest. I have added an answer.

Answer (score 5):

Another possible solution would be to get a list of the line2D objects and then change the linewidths using `set_linewidth()`

```
lines = ax.lines
for line in lines:

    line.set_linewidth(2)
```

Comment: Nice. I have not tried this as the solution before worked but will give it a go as well.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with `plot_matches` is that it can create a number of possible artists on the axes, depending on the inputs, and therefore does not have a return value with the new objects as many plotting functions do. You can extend @DavidG's answer to check which lines were added specifically by your call to `plot_matches`. This would make your code slightly more complex, but may be worth the effort, depending on your needs:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage.feature import plot_matches

def my_plot_matches(ax, *args, line_options={}, **kwargs):
    nlines = len(ax.lines)
    plot_matches(ax, *args, **kwargs)
    new_lines = ax.lines[nlines:]
    if new_lines and line_options:
        plt.setp(new_lines, **line_options)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.gray()
my_plot_matches(ax, img1, img2, k1[:, [0, 1]], k2[:, [0, 1]], matches, only_matches=True, line_options={'linewidth': 2})
ax.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

This version relies on the fact that anything that `plot_matches` draws on the axes gets appended to the internal list of line objects. I assume that anything not in the list before `plot_matches` is at the end of the list and needs to be modified.

Comment: Much too complicated if you ask me. ;-) Unless you name a case where my answer would not work.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest. Completely agree. Basically added from boredom. I would go with your answer myself any day.

Comment: Ok, +1 for boredom!

Comment: Good to know as well. Thank you for this.